# kotlin firebase remove child

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete a specific value from a firebase realtime database, but I don't know how to do it because I don't know to save or find the key value of the child which is automatically generate.

[image]

If you see the picture I've only managed to remove all the children from the first key with

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Comentarios").removeValue()
```

But I need to delete just by the child ***creadoPor***

Is there any way of skkiping an unnamed child?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Comentarios").removeValue()
```

But I need to delete just by the child `creadoPor`.

Comment: Do you know any of the values in the path of the node that you're trying to delete? I.e. "-NGi7xP...", "-NGkzW....", and/or "R7lji3..."? If so, which ones are know, and which ones aren't?

Comment: Yes know -NGitxP... and R7lji3... but none of -NGkzW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the "grantparent" key of the data and the value of one of the nodes properties, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to find the nodes that match that value.

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref("Comentarios")
  .child("-NGi7xP...")
  .orderByChild("creadoPor")
  .equalTo("R7lji3...")
```

When you get the `DataSnapshot` from the query, you'll need to loop over its children as shown in the documentation on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events). Even when there's only one result, you'll get a list of one child node and thus will need to loop over them.

Comment: so I have to do denormalization is it?